# Google analitycs alternative?

Tags: php, mysql, analytics

Is there other free tracking software like google analytics where you can create funnel and see how many people did specific action e.g.

apr.27.2012

```
went to wqebsite (100) -> leave site from homepage (40) (average stay 18 seconds)
 |
 V
go to products (60) -> went to shopping cart page (12)

 | --|
 |   ---> closed site (43)
 V
went to terms page (5)
```

or assign anonymous id to user like kissmetrics and later you can see all actions done by this usser

Comment: Maybe belongs on webmasters? Not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yandex has one in Russia, not on the Wikipedia list. It looks pretty nice too. I saw it used for a Russian site, but it is available in english too, much like Google. metrika.yandex.com for english.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to ["List of web analytics software"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software) on Wikipedia, especially the "Hosted" part.

You may also have a look at [Google Analytics Competitors](http://www.cloudsurfing.com/site/3582-Google-Analytics/competitors/) from CloudSurfing.